# Simple security between prototype iPhone app and Python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, ios, http, rest, authentication

I'm prototyping a simple data collection service. I've implemented a simple REST API implemented with python 3x stock HTTPServer. And a simple iPhone app that submits data via a json/POST. And it all works just great when my iPhone is on the same network as the server.

But now I want to go the next step. I don't need to move beyond prototype/PoC yet, I just want to be able to do it outside of our internal network. Issues of getting access, name resolution, a port and that kind of stuff... what kind of security should I add to it? I'm new to that part (and the other stuff as well I guess).

I found [this example](https://gist.github.com/ubershmekel/6194556) of how to add SSL to my python service. If I can figure out how to get the right keys embedded into my iPhone app (it's just on my phone, not anyone else's), is that enough. Or should I include some sort of auth? If so, what kind? And any pointers to how to start that would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The code I came up with, after switching to Tornado per the suggestions, for others' reference, looks something like this:

```
import tornado, tornado.web, tornado.httpserver

#Create a "Application" that links the restful URL with a custom class named RestHandler
RestServices = tornado.web.Application([(r'/twig_monikers', RestHandler)])

#Startup tornado
def main():
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(RestServices,
        ssl_options={'certfile': 'cert', 'keyfile': 'key'}) #This is where you put the paths to your generated cert and key files.
    server.listen(44321) #start on port 44321
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Invoke `main` appropriately of course. The only other part, is to create a `RestHandler` class to handle any URLs that end in `/twig_monikers`

```
class RestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def authenticate(self): #implements basic auth checking of the Authorization header
        header = self.request.headers.get('Authorization', '')
        passed = False
        if header.startswith('Basic '):
            userPass = base64.b64decode(header[6:].encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
            user , password = userPass.split(':')
            passed = user == 'acceptable_username' and password == 'acceptable_password'
        if not passed:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403)

    def put(self): #causes our RestHandler to respond to HTTP 'PUT' verbs
        self.authenticate() #first validate the packet
        keyedValues = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf8'))
        self.doSomethingWithJsonPayload(keyedValues)

    def doSomethingWithJsonPayload(self, keyedValues):
        pass #do your own thing here
```

Comment: `http.server` can only handle one request at a time. Implement your REST API with Tornado or some other non-blocking web framework.

Comment: At this point of prototyping, I'm far from that (blocking) being an issue. My iPhone is the only guy that has code that can hit the service. But I'm not opposed to using a higher level/more robust framework eventually. In fact, I fully expect it, should things go well. Sill it just end up being more overhead than I want at the moment? More importantly, will it make adding the appropriate security at this point easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.server` is fairly low-level. I would use a lightweight web framework to write your REST service, as many already have plugins for authentication and wrappers for REST services.

I primarily use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) and [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/overview.html). Both have plugins/built-in classes for authentication and RESTful APIs:

- [Flask-Restless](http://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Flask-Login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Tornado-REST](https://github.com/rancavil/tornado-rest)
- [Tornado authentication](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/overview.html#id1)

Neither authentication wrappers assume anything about your setup. As for your actual REST service, use HTTPS and implement some sort of API token to identify users. Both frameworks support HTTPS so it'll be trivial to implement.

Comment: I ended up switching to Tornado, and life was easier/nicer. I'll post some example code in an answer of my own below.